# Why does 'fbi' not show splash image during system startup?

Tags: splash-screen, raspbian, systemd

I'm trying to provide a splashscreen for Raspbian Stretch using fbi. Based upon some tutorials I found here my situation:

/etc/systemd/system/splashscreen.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Splash screen
DefaultDependencies=no
After=local-fs.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbi -T 1 -d /dev/fb0 --noverbose /opt/logo.png

[Install]
WantedBy=sysinit.target
```

enabled (checked the symlink under sysinit.target.wants).

/boot/cmdline.txt

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=ee397c53-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait quiet logo.nologo loglevel=1 fsck.mode=skip noswap ro consoleblank=0
```

p

/boot/config.txt

```
hdmi_drive=2
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on
dtparam=i2c1=on
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds1307
disable_splash=1
```

Executing the exactly same command (`fbi -T 1 -d /dev/fb0 --noverbose /opt/logo.png`) from prompt leads to show the image as expected.

In the boot messages I can't find any error. Any thought?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got this to work!  Here's what I did (essentially copied from https://yingtongli.me/blog/2016/12/21/splash.html, with a few small changes that made it work for me).

1. Install fbi: `apt install fbi`
2. Create `/etc/systemd/system/splashscreen.service` with:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Splash screen
   DefaultDependencies=no
   After=local-fs.target

   [Service]
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/fbi --noverbose -a /opt/splash.png
   StandardInput=tty
   StandardOutput=tty

   [Install]
   WantedBy=sysinit.target
   ```

   The only thing I did differently from the article linked above is remove the `-d` flag from the `/usr/bin/fbi` command (the command was originally `/usr/bin/fbi -d /dev/fb0 --noverbose -a /opt/splash.png`). I'm guessing `fb0` was the wrong device and leaving it out just means `fbi` will use the current display device and gets it right.
3. Put your splash images in `/opt/splash.png`.
4. Enable the service: `systemctl enable splashscreen`

I'm still trying to figure out how to get rid of the rest of the boot text, but this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: In case you figured out how to remove the rest of the boot messages, could you update your answer on this topic?

Comment: @MWiesner I tried quite a few things, but never completely got rid of boot messages :/

Comment: Regarding the console output of the kernel: You can redirect it to another TTY, so you don't see it on the first one (the one displayed by default).

This is done by adding to the kernel line (in /boot/cmdline.txt on Raspbian) the following options : `console=tty1` → `console=tty2` for example (we often see tty3 selected in other forums) it moves basic information to tty2 (like `[ OK ] netword started`) ; `loglevel=1` will remove all the debug dmesg on the TTY (it keeps sending it to tty1) ; `logo.nologo` will remove the penguins or Raspberries